# Connecting to BitBucket from Fasthosts

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I don't know enough about SSH to figure out where I might be going wrong.  I'm trying to set up my project on a server but can't connect via ssh. SO, I've;

- generated an ssh key on the server (a shared hosting package)
- .bash_profile is starting ssh-agent and loading my key. `ssh-add -l` spits out the key
- added the public key as a deployment key on BitBucket repo

But when I try `ssh -t git@bitbucket.org` or `git pull` all I get is a timeout after a few minutes.  If I change the `git remote` to use https://@bitbucket.org/[user]/[repo] and pull I get a connection...

Is it possible for my host to block ssh connections while allowing other functionality?
Does the repo on bitbucket need any settings to allow Deployment keys (other than adding the key under 'Deployment Keys')

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1. Try `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`. Capital 'T' as a key.

2. Try to check private key explicitly by using -i: `ssh -i ./your_private_key -T git@bitbucket.org`

Comment: I submitted a Support Ticket to Fasthosts and they responded with _"Please be informed that we dont currently allow port 22 outbound from the ssh server or the web servers so that wont work. Its a security measure to prevent our servers being used to bruteforce peoples ssh servers so its unlikely something that we would enable"_ ...